# Add 30 seconds to the time with PHP

Tags: php, time

How can I add 30 seconds to this time?

```
$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time());
```

I wasn't sure how to do it because it is showing lots of different units of time, when I only want to add 30 seconds.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time() + 30);
```

Answer (score 17):

If you're using php 5.3+, check out the [DateTime::add operations](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) or `modify`, really much easier than this.

For example:

```
$startTime = new DateTime("09:00:00");
$endTime = new DateTime("19:00:00");


while($startTime < $endTime) {

$startTime->modify('+30 minutes'); // can be seconds, hours.. etc

echo $startTime->format('H:i:s')."<br>";
break;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

What about using strtotime? The code would then be:

```
strtotime( '+30 second' );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time() + 30);

//or

$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", strtotime("+30 seconds"));
```

Answer (score 3):

General :

```
$add_time=strtotime($old_date)+30;
$add_date= date('m/d/Y h:i:s a',$add_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

See mktime:

```
mktime (date("H"), date("i"), date("s") + 30)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

should do what you want.

Comment: Because it ugly. If `date("s")` for example returns 50, than it will be 50 + 30 = 80, what is not a valid number of seconds in a 'time'. Better just use time() + 30 (it is more logical).

Comment: "Because it ugly" is a reason for the down vote, not a reason for down voting with no comment.  Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: and make time will handle the 80 and convert it up....that's it's job.

You could put 8,000,000 as the seconds and it would convert it to a proper date, mktime does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s", time());
$ts = strtotime($time);
$addtime = date("m/d/Y h:i:s", mktime(date("h", $ts),date("i", $ts),date("s", $ts)+30,date("Y", $ts),date("m", $ts),date("d", $ts));
```

Would be a more explained version of all of the above.