# Php subtracts second from digit

Tags: php

How is it possible using php to substract seconds from a Digit time?

How example if I have this time:

```
00:01:30
```

and I want to subtract this by 3 second which would make this

```
00:01:27
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463549/subtract-time-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. It's really powerful and a godsend.

```
<?php     
$date = new DateTime("2017-11-20 00:01:30");
$date->modify("-3 seconds");
echo $date->format("H:i:s");
//output :00:01:27
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the modify function to subtract the seconds, as below.

```
$timeStr = new DateTime("09:00:00");

$timeStr->modify('-3 seconds'); // can be seconds, hours.. etc

echo $timeStr->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer borrowed from [Add 30 seconds to the time with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052865/add-30-seconds-to-the-time-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class is very helpful and has more flexibility with formats and such. However, for this isolated example, it can be done as:

```
$time = '00:01:30';
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($time .' - 3 seconds'));
```

Which produces:
`00:01:27`

**Edit:**

Per the comment about microseconds, the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function does not support this.

> Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always
>   generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas
>   DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created
>   with microseconds.

As stated above, and in the other answers, the DateTime class in PHP is much more flexible for formatting dates. It allows for timezone support with [`setTimezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) and multiple input formats with [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Hi what about if I want - 1/10 of a second?